# Filter forward col 1 without iteration

Tags: python, pandas, iteration

I am dealing with a "waterfall" structure DataFrame in Pandas, Python.

Column 1 is full, while the rest of the data set is mostly empty representing series available for only a subset of the total period considered:

```
Instrument AUPRATE. AIB0411 AIB0511 AIB0611  ... AIB1120 AIB1220 AIB0121 AIB0221
Field                                        ...                                
Date                                         ...                                
2011-03-31     4.75   4.730   4.710   4.705  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2011-04-29     4.75   4.745   4.750   4.775  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2011-05-31     4.75     NaN   4.745   4.755  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2011-06-30     4.75     NaN     NaN   4.745  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2011-07-29     4.75     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
            ...     ...     ...     ...  ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
2019-05-31     1.50     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2019-06-28     1.25     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...   0.680     NaN     NaN     NaN
2019-07-31     1.00     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...   0.520   0.530     NaN     NaN
2019-08-30     1.00     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...   0.395   0.405   0.405     NaN
2019-09-30     1.00     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...   0.435   0.445   0.445    0.45
```

What I would like to do is to push the values from "AUPRATE" to the start of the data in every row (such that they effectively represent the zeroth observation). Where the AUPRATE values are not adjacent to the dataset, they should be replaced with NaN.

I could probably write a junky loop to do this but I was wondering if there was an efficient way of achieving the same outcome.

I am very much a novice in pandas and Python. Thank you in advance.

[edit]

Desired output:

```
Instrument AUPRATE. AIB0411 AIB0511 AIB0611  ... AIB1120 AIB1220 AIB0121 AIB0221
Field                                        ...                                
Date                                         ...                                
2011-03-31     4.75   4.730   4.710   4.705  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2011-04-29     4.75   4.745   4.750   4.775  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2011-05-31     NaN     4.75   4.745   4.755  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2011-06-30     NaN     NaN     4.75   4.745  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2011-07-29     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

I have implemented the following, based on the suggestion below. I would still be happy if there was a way of doing this without iteration.

```
for i in range(AU_furures_rates.shape[0]):                                                              #iterate over rows
    for j in range(AU_furures_rates.shape[1]-1):                                                        #iterate over cols
        if (pd.notnull(AU_furures_rates.iloc[i,j+1])) and pd.isnull(AU_furures_rates.iloc[i,1]):        #move rate when needed
            AU_furures_rates.iloc[i,j] = AU_furures_rates.iloc[i,0]
            AU_furures_rates.iloc[i,0] = "NaN"
            break
```

Comment: Request you not to post images in form of data, always post sample of input and expected output in form of text which is wrapped in CODE TAGS, kindly edit your question and let us know then.

Comment: Could you try rephrasing your question so that it is less cryptic? It seems like what you're trying to do is simple, yet I am unable to understand what is exactly you're setting out to do! Hope this helps.

Comment: can you share your desired output

Comment: @ RavinderSingh13 done, apologies for the faux pas

Comment: @M_S_N: desired output added

Comment: @manuel Martinez: desired output added, thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone would find a 'cleaner' solution, but what I thought about was first iterating over the columns, to check for each row which is the column whose value you need to replace (backwards, so that it'll end up with the first occurance) with:

```
df['column_to_move'] = np.nan
cols = df.columns.tolist()
for i in range(len(df) - 2, 1, -1):
    df.loc[pd.isna(df[cols[i]]) & pd.notna(df[cols[i + 1]]), 'column_to_move'] = cols[i]
```

And then iterate the columns to fill the value from `AUPRATE.` to where its needed, and change `AUPRATE.` itself with `np.nan` with:

`for col in cols[2: -1]:
    df.loc[df['column_to_move'] == col, col] = df['AUPRATE.']
    df.loc[df['column_to_move'] == col, 'AUPRATE.'] = np.nan
df.drop('column_to_move', axis=1, inplace=True)`

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll give it a try.